# Insufficient rights to open a development workspace Microsoft Dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I'm new to Dynamics ax. I've just install this product. The database server(sql server 2014) is in another Server, and also the Active directory role is installed on the server(windows server 2012R2).

A user account created on the AD which is member of "Local Admin" which caused the created user be the administrator of computer which he logins. Then I installed AX in windows7 client which joint to the Domain server with the created user.

I configure and pass the checklist and create a new admin user in AX(System administration=>Common=>Users),too. but when execute "ax32.exe -development", the error raised.
how can I pass this error to open the development workspace

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you post the complete error message text? Also make sure that the license used and the active configuration keys allow development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand that when you open the AX client, it opens in a "Workspace" mode by default.

If you have the correct rights, you can open a "Development Workspace" through several methods.

In the upper right, you can access it, or you can press (Ctrl+Shift+W)
[image: Screenshot]

Executing "ax32.exe -development" is just passing an argument to tell the AX client that you would prefer jumping directly into the Development Workspace.

Your error is likely because of spaces in your path if you are calling it like this:

> `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe -Development`

When you should put quotes around the path and call it like this:

> `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe" -Development`